# Vuejs, Universal app, compile is not a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have **vuejs** application, build with **nuxt cli**. One vue component needs to load dynamic template, then compile on the fly. When building as universal application, it throws error:

> TypeError vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.compile is not a
>   function

If I build the application as SPA (mode: 'spa'), it can works, but doesn't work for universal mode.

I guess it's because the server side bundle is not using the right javascript, anyone know how to fix this

component

```
data() {
    return {
      template: null
    }
  },
render(createElement) {
   this.template = Vue.compile('<div>Test</div>').render
   return createElement('div', [this.template ? this.template() : ''])
}


nuxt.config.js
    build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you read this section of the Vue docs? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

Comment: Yes, so I tried adding below to nuxt.config.js, that solves the problem when running in SPA mode, but still has the same problem when running in "Universal" mode .extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }

Comment: have you found a solution?